# Issues importing a png file to Latex

Tags: graphics, xetex, png

I'm having trouble compiling my document since I added a figure to it. Checked the other related questions, but so far solutions did not apply... I'd be thankful for your insights! This is what the set up looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese, german, spanish, english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }
...
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{"Images/Key Category colors 8"}
\caption{Visual representation ...}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please do not post code snippets but always a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) from `\documentclass` till `\end{document}` without `...` in the document preamble (and mostly also in the document body).

Answer (score 1):

With deactivated shorthands and correct path to the file it should work:

```
\shorthandoff{"}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{"Key Category colors 8"}
\shorthandon{"}
```

Nevertheless, I would recommend not to use white spaces in file names. Rename `Key Category colors 8.png` to, e.g., `Key-Category-colors-8.png` and use:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Key-Category-colors-8}
```

`Images/` as part of the file name argument is not needed, because you have already `\graphicspath{{Images/}}`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) The tip about the file names did the trick!

Comment: @Deb: Please have a look at [the tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) (already linked in the welcome comment) to see how "thank you" can be done by voting for (or accepting) an answer.